# python requests captcha form

Tags: python, python-requests, recaptcha, captcha

I'm filling a form using requests and python but i'm blocked with the recaptcha.
I need to send a g-recaptcha-response but I don't know how to get it.

Here is the website code:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-callback="checkoutAfterCaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeWwRkUAAAAAOBsau7xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx" data-size="invisible">
  <div class="grecaptcha-badge" data-style="bottomright" style="width: 256px; height: 60px; transition: right 0.3s ease; position: fixed; bottom: 14px; right: -186px; box-shadow: gray 0px 0px 5px;">
    <div class="grecaptcha-logo">
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6LeWwRkUAAAAAOBsau7KpuC9AV-6J8mhw4AjC3Xz&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc3VwcmVtZW5ld3lvcmsuY29tOjQ0Mw..&amp;hl=fr&amp;v=v1525674693836&amp;size=invisible&amp;cb=g8s5582r6zik" width="256" height="60"
        role="presentation" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox" kwframeid="3">
      </iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="grecaptcha-error">
    </div>
    <textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;  display: none; ">
    </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is my code, I manage to get the data-sitekey but I don't understand how to get the g-recaptcha-response:

```
page = c.get(link_checkout)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    find_class = soup.find(class_='g-recaptcha')
    get_captcha_token = find_class.get('data-sitekey')
    print (get_captcha_token)
    # try:
    #     content = requests.post(
    #         'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
    #         data={
    #             'secret': RECAPTCHA_SECRET,
    #             'response': get_captcha_token,
    #             'remoteip': ip
    #         }
    #     ).content
    # except:
    #     print ("fail")
    # print (get_captcha_token)

    c.post(url, data=payload_FORM, headers={"Refered": link_checkout})
    page = c.get(link_checkout)
```

thank you all for your help! This is my last probleme to finish my programme and there is really little on google

If you need more info tell me in the coms I will add it